# how can linking SQLite database with android app interface

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-sqlite, android-tabs

how I can link SQLite Database with Android app interface ??

to build the database I applied this way :

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

but when I try to run the app, the database didn't work !!

- I have done all steps ::

  1. Copy android-sqlite-asset-helper.jar into your Android project's libs directory and add it to the build path.
  2. put the database in Zip file in libs file

in the following link u can see a picture of my app page that has tabs in each tab (track) there is list of courses that I put it in database file.

my problem when I click on any tab (track) it doesn't open to show the courses list & course description (that is exist in database file).

http://s30.postimg.org/thfrmhlkh/Screenshot_2013_12_15_15_22_21.png

this page contain:

1. Faculties (it is working)
2. Tracks for each faculty (it is working)
3. List of courses in each track (it isn't working "database")
4. page for course description (by use fragment, it isn't working "database")

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure about your problem.

> 2) put the database in Zip file in libs file

Still, Try to put the zip file in a folder called databases inside assets (assets/databases/your_file.zip). The zip file should contain only one file, the sqlite file.